# Teradata CLOB and JDBC : The Locator is invalid because it has been changed ERROR

Tags: java, jdbc, teradata, clob

I'm trying to copy `CLOB` from one database to another. However I get `The Locator is invalid because it has been changed` error.

This [article](https://developer.teradata.com/blog/tomnolan/2016/03/lob-locator-lifetime) says this can happen because `ResultSet`, `PreparedStamenent` are closed. However all my objects are open. And the error is thrown when I try to `executeBatch()`

```
 Statement select = connectionDB1.createStatement(); 
 ResultSet rs = select.executeQuery("SELECT TOP 1 myClob FROM myTab"); 
 rs.next();  
 PreparedStatement ps = connectionDB2.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO myTab2 SELECT ? ");
 ps.setClob(1, rs.getClob(1)); 
 System.out.println("CLOB inserted");
 ps.addBatch();
 ps.executeBatch(); // ERROR is thrown here before I close any objects WHY? 
                   // java.sql.BatchUpdateException
```

**Why does this happen? How to prevent this?**

---

PS: The above code runs well with any other data type: VARCHAR, DECIMAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article says that the CLOB is a locator that is valid in the same session.

But when you try to apply it to another connection,  you are using it in a *different* session,  so the error occurs.

What you need to do is to read the actual CLOB content from the source database and write it into the target database.

Comment: Thank you +1. What do you mean by `read the actual CLOB content ` ? Do you mena to write the original CLOB to a local file and then to read from that file and load it to the target database?

Comment: This could be the best option if you already know you're talking of very large texts and you can use some Teradata tools for loading.  If you want to remain in Jdbc,  I think you could just get the characterStream from source CLOB and set it as an input for the target CLOB.

Comment: You can find some good examples of Lob management in these Teradata jdbc samples (http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samplePrograms.html)